# upload laravel on siteground routes not working

Tags: laravel

when upload the laravel on the siteground server it workes put the routes not working

I tried to upload htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(css|js|images)/(.*)$ public/$1/$2 [L,NC]
```

so why the routs is not wroking ?

Comment: Is the root of your web host pointing to the `public` folder?

Comment: i use mydomain/public for now and the routes not working

Answer (score 1):

You will likely have to put your public part of laravel within /public_html and not /public which is what Lavavel is expecting.  So create a symbolic link to create a fake /public folder:

```
ln -s public_html public
```